# Link between the $L_1$ distance between CDFs and PDFs?

Tags: distributions, distance, inequality

Let $F:(-\infty,\infty)\rightarrow[0,1]$ and $G:(-\infty,\infty)\rightarrow[0,1]$ be two CDFs with PDFs $f$ and $g$, respectively. Is there a connection/inequality between:

$$d_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\vert f(t) - g(t) \vert dt,$$
and
$$d_2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\vert F(t) - G(t) \vert dt?$$
Assuming $d_2$ exists ($d_1$ is always finite).

Comment: Since one integral gives information about probabilities and the other about expectations, there is no reason to expect any relationship at all.

Comment: @whuber That's a good point but, since $d_1$ is twice the Total Variation distance and $d_2$ is the Kantorovich, I was expecting to find a connection (e.g. one dominates the other under some general conditions).

Comment: @Merlot: I think $d_{1} \geqslant d_{2}$. I tried a couple of cases comparing $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ in my derivation and that seems to be the case.

Comment: The first integral is invariant under change of the unit of measurement, but the second is not.  That implies there is no relationship between them.